# How are pthreads implemented in Linux kernel(>2.6) using NPTL?

Tags: linux, pthreads, nptl

I have come across the POSIX-compliant NPTL(native posix thread library) been mentioned at several forums.
I want to understand how pthreads are implemented with the support of the kernel(linux).
Can anyone please provide a reference to a good material that explains the design and implementation of pthreads in linux ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this paper of design and implementation of NPTL by Ulrich Drepper and Ingo Molnar
http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/nptl-design.pdf

I believe a lot had been changed since 2005 and it's not should be used as a reference to point out limitations and shortcomings (that said in header), though it's a great doc about overall design.

Comment: Its a very old document, and I am not sure if the rationale explained exists at all. what do you say ?

Comment: A lot of the programmers don't like to write documentation, so imho once that paper was written nobody wanted to update it. Last resort is source code (linux kernel and glibc) itself.